# Dual field unique indices

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm using mongodb at present but i've also been accustomed to MySQL.

I'm trying to ponder can we have a dual field index?

For instance imagine this table:

```
Firstname   | LastName
============+=================    
Bob         | Bob
Bob         | B
John        | Bob
```

A index where we can have the database enforce uniqueness with both the `First Name` and `Last Name` as one (wihout having to have an overhead as a third field as both combined or as a hash or something

so if we were to Enter `{ 'firstname: 'bob', 'lastname': 'bob'}` it wouldn't insert.

Can mongodb do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in MongoDB through a compound index, like so :

```
db.col.ensureIndex({Firstname:1, LastName:1}, {unique:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provided you with the ability to have both compound keys and unique indexes. You can find information regarding this via the following link:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-unique%3Atrue

Here, there is an example to what you are looking for:

db.things.ensureIndex({firstname: 1, lastname: 1}, {unique: true});

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You can add Multiple column indexes in mysql. For example:

```
alter table users add unique index(firstname, lastname);
```

**UPDATE:**

This is called a *composite unique constraint*